# Does dropout applies to regularization term in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regularized, dropout

I have a customized regularization term `my_reg`.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# The last layer is regularized with a custom regularizer
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', W_regularizer=my_reg))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

Will the `Dropout(0.5)` also applies to `my_reg` during the training process? If not, how can I make it to be true? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Dropout works by dropping neurons, setting their activation to be zero, so this conceptually also affects the weights associated for that neuron, which you might consider as "applying" to any regularization terms, but note that the weights are never explicitly set to zero, so you will see little change on the regularization coefficient effect.

Comment: Thanks Matias! I'm not entirely sure about your last statement. Suppose I added an L2 regularizer to a layer that applied by Dropout (0.5). Then there will be 50% of the weights being updated by the L2 regularizer, and another 50% will not change in this iteration, so the regularization effect is changed, right?

Comment: @PiggyWenzhou Its complicated, because the weights are not set to zero, the activation of the neuron is set to zero, so the gradient is zero, but the weights are not zero, so they still are considered in the L2 regularization, the weights associated with the dropped neuron won't change, but these weights are still used when computing the L2 regularization term.